# DC Stepper Motor vs DC Gearmotor

Tags: motor, dc-motor, stepper-motor, motor-controller, stepper-driver

We are trying to come up with a way to turn an auger type shaft as slowly as possible to continuously dispense a very small amount of particulates (~ 5 grams per minute).  Would a DC gearmotor with a speed control drive work best or would a DC stepper motor be a better solution?

Comment: "as slowly as possible" is a meaningless objective. Calculate how many revolutions per minute will dispense 5 grams per minute of the substance. Determine how much torque is required to turn the device at that speed. Is there significant static friction that must be overcome before the device will move? Is it important to dispense smoothly? Does the rate of dispensing need to be closely adjusted?

Comment: Stepper doesn't need separate speed control, but you'd probably want to use a geared stepper anyway. 28BYJ-48 claims > 34 mN.m of torque, and they're cheap as chips.

Comment: Does the speed or dispensing rate need to be adjustable?  Can the auger design be altered to dispense the desired amount based on a fixed speed?  You might be able to use a either small AC synchronous (clock) motor or a small shaded-pole motor with gearbox.

Answer (score 1):

DC motors work best in applications where the speed needs to be continuous. Conversely, stepper motors (as the name implies) move in discrete steps, even if a gear reduction is used. That may or may not be a problem in your application.

Sure, a DC motor experiences "cogging", a similar behavior, though not nearly as intense as stepping. For sure, a DC motor will work well for slow speed applications.

Also, if the speed is fixed, a DC gearmotor works with a fixed-voltage power supply: no motor driver is needed (unlike a stepper motor).

Comment: "Sure, a DC motor experiences "cogging"," But if you're using a gear train, you can run the motor at a high enough speed to avoid any noticeable cogging.

Answer (score 1):

A stepper motor's advantages is inherent holding torque and open-loop stepping which lets you "know" the position of the stepper motor without any feedback if you can assume that the motor never slips, and you can spin slowly without a gearbox or feedback. It's disadvantage is low output power, especially at high speeds.

A traditional DC motor's advantage is high continuous power output, balanced between output torque and speed. It's disadvantage is to hold position you need feeback, and for low speed rotation you probably need a gearbox (and perhaps also feedback).

So it basically comes down to the torque requirements and motion requirements in your application.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how do you measure the speed and what do you do to control it.

For instance, let's assume you have a syringe and you need to move it's plunger at linear speed of 5mm/min = 0.083mm/sec.

I would consider the following options:

1. Voice coil motor/linear motor with high resolution encoder sin/cos. This is the most expensive and the most accurate solution. Also probably pretty easy to implement. However poses requirements for a motor drive- high resolution current measurement. But totally doable.
2. Brushless motor rotating a screw. Essentially it's the same, only the screw acts as a gear and allows you to move the working point. If you take a screw with a pitch of 0.25mm, your speed needs to be 18RPM, which is around the lower edge of reasonable range for a brushless motor controller. However, with a good encoder and high accuracy current sensing it should not be a problem. Still voice coil seems a simpler system.
3. Brushless + gear (1:100?) + screw. Well, in this case you don't need too accurate of an encoder, but you get a more complex system with artifacts of the gear. However maintaining speed of 1800RPM in this case is peanuts for any reasonable servo.
4. Stepper + screw. You will not get a really constant speed. At least you need to use microsteps (pretty trivial today) but still the movement will not be very steady. Is it good enough? I don't know, maybe. But in a similar application i am developing now it seems too risky- i need an even extrusion of volume.

So if it was me, depending on how mass the application is, it would be either 1 or 3. 1 if it's a one-off lab system, 3 if you are going to make hundreds. 4 and 2 only consider if you move past 10000 units and every penny matters.